# MKMapView behind a UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, mkmapview

Im trying to replicate how the map view is placed behind the tableview and when scrolled down expanding the mapview and when scrolling up covering the map view. Any ideas on how to implement this. From what i know, the table view will cover the whole view and insent to the height of the map view which would be placed behind the tableview
The images best show the look I am trying to achieve.
Any help would be appreciated[image: ![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdEr1.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `MKMapView` inside the table cell , but you need to make this

```
  segment
  mapView // height = 200 / 600
  table
```

and play with the height constraint of the mapview to collpase/expand the map

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the library [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley). It imitates the drawer found in the native Maps app.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, I placed the map view behind the table view and the whole table covering the view and setting the tableviews background colour to clear, I inset to the height of the tableview to the map views height and added a top constraint to the mapview which I use to move the map when scrolled:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let distance = self.tableView.contentInset.top + self.tableView.contentOffset.y
    self.mapViewTopConstraint.constant = -distance * 0.4

}
```

0.4 is the rate in which I slow the mapview going up